# PHP Queue System with Codeigniter. HOW?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, queue

I am creating a website for a client where they need the ability to generate 25,000 - 100,000 barcodes. I have licensed a software that generates the codes but it takes around 20 - 30 minutes to generate an order of say. 60,000 barcodes.

So my question is this...

Would it be possible to use the set time limit function in php set to zero (no time limit) and then pass the variables to the library with Ajax and use the ignore_user_abort function. This way essentially this is what would happen:

Customer chooses barcode qty and type, they check out and after the payment gateway sends back a response of SUCCESSFUL, then we run an ajax request that sets the time limit to UNLIMITED and then tells the script to run even if the user closes their browser or exits the page. This way the server processes the order and it doesn't matter if it takes 2 seconds or 45 minutes. When the order is done the client can refresh their account and they would see their order.

Am I just dreaming to think that this sounds like a good idea or would it be a viable solution? I don't have any experience in my years of coding with php queue systems, so I don't want to have to create one unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: This response is really not helpful in the least. I don't really want to go into why the customer needs to generate that amount of barcodes or what type of barcode it is. I already have a very well developed solution for creating the barcodes. They are EPS, PDF and JPEG vector barcodes. If you read my question again, you'll understand what I'm asking. Has nothing to do with barcode creation but rather how to Make a process that could take 20 minutes, regardless of what the process is, functional without a queue system.

Comment: And another thing, if it helps you for whatever reason, he is one of the largest barcode retailers on the internet and the majority of his orders are between 10 - 250 barcodes. But in his 5 years in business he has received around 200 orders that fall into the category of 25,000 - 100,000 barcodes.

Comment: this not specific to Code Igniter. You basically just need a queue of some sort. Should not be hard to find. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=job+queues+php and the Related Section to the right for some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at using something like Gearman ( http://gearman.org/index.php ).

This would also be separate to the CI app ... CI will then use Gearman to process a queue...

Comment: I know it's an old Post - but i found this promising library https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-queue-worker

Answer (score 1):

Don't depend on one long-running PHP instance. Especially if it's tied to the user/browser in any way. Properly separate the backend system from ephemeral processes like web server responses.

Make a proper queue-worker system. Put all orders into a queue (database, flat file, whatever) and have a worker take orders from the queue one by one, process them, update the result. The worker can be a cron job, a daemon process, an endless looping PHP script (which is restarted by a monitor if it crashes) or whatever else. You can also look into AMQP, ZeroMQ or similar queuing/messaging systems.

Comment: so would something like this work:

1. Add the necessary information to a database table
2. Run a cron every 5 minutes that pulls the latest queue table item and runs the process that generates the barcodes and makes it available to the client, then if successful, deletes that table item?

Comment: Yes, but: Running that cron job only every 5 minutes means orders may be unnecessarily delayed for 5 minutes. That may or may not be a problem. And it depends on what you mean by "makes available to client". If successful, the worker should update the database with "job done, the result can be found here...". The client will have to poll every once in a while "is it done yet, is it done yet" to get the update. That, or send an email or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CLI at backend, it doesn't have timelimit by default.. http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

What I mean in 3 steps..

First save the ORDER at your database..

Second!!!
Set crontask to run each minute, to take and proccess 1 order.
When order is ready (after 30minutes) update the database with download links or what ever you return as responde and end the crontasks.

Third. 
After his order is ready show to user at some page the result.

Comment: Its the same as getting withdraw from Paypal ... You make order, wait something to proccess it and at end you get that your order is completed..