# Synchronized or queue in PHP , Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one scenario where multiple users try to hit one function and it performs some operations on the database.

But because of this some time many requests came at the same time at this time some operations on the database are failed.

For that, I need a solution like Java synchronizes method which manages request in queues.

I have tried to find many solutions but I didn't get any solution for it.

provide me some guidance on it.

The script is written in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: You have taged laravel and codeigniter to different frameworks.

Comment: @GufranHasan script don't have any special code there is normal operation. it has  insert query

Comment: @user4419336 yes that i know, i need some logic for both farmework

Comment: Please see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065975/php-queue-system-with-codeigniter-how

Comment: Somewhat agree with the answer given in post suggested by "@Gufan Hasan".

You may need to change the way you are doing and use database as suggested.